# Display preferences ruined my fullscreen application [macOS]

Tags: macos

I have an application running on one monitor on fullscreen mode, but when user open display preferences (from other monitor), the fullscreen mode will be ruined, how to avoid that?
Some thoughts:
 1. Is there any API which could deny user from opening Display Preference?
 2. If fullscreen mode was pushed off by display preference window, does application get any notification?
 3. When user open display preferences, is there any notification broadcast to application (Quartz APIs)?

T2 & T3 is for application to get the chance to switch back to fullscreen mode

Comment: windowDidExitedFullScreen might be what I'm hunting

Comment: Does QT QWidget have signal for windowDidExitFullscreen ?